# create a rolling buffer in bash

Tags: bash, curl, shell

I want to use curl to get a stream from a remote server, and write it to a buffer. So far so good I just do `curl http://the.stream>/path/to/thebuffer`. Thing is I don't want this file to get too large, so I want to be able to delete the first bytes of the file as I simultaneously add to the last bytes. Is there a way of doing this?

Alternatively if I could write n bytes to buffer1, then switch to buffer2, buffer3.. and when buffer x was reached delete buffer1 and start again - without losing the data coming in from curl (it's a live stream, so I can't stop curl). I've been reading up the man pages for curl and cat and read, but can't see anything promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any particularly easy way to do what you are seeking to do.

Probably the nearest approach creates a FIFO, and redirects the output of `curl` to the FIFO.  You then have a program such as [`split`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/split.html) or [`csplit`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/csplit.html) reading the FIFO and writing to different files.  If you decide that the split programs are not the tool, you may need to write your own variation on them.  You can then decide how to process the files that are created, and when to remove them.

Note that `curl` will hang until there is a process reading from the FIFO.  When the process reading the FIFO exits, `curl` will get either a SIGPIPE signal or a write error, either of which should stop it.